# Would this question be considered on topic or not too broad?

Tags: discussion

**What alcohol products go well with a particular type of coffee?**

I enjoy the odd [Irish Coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_coffee) occasionally.

What alcohol products go well with a particular type of coffee?

Desiring to expand my coffee/alcohol combos, I would like to know what types of coffee goes well with what type of alcohol?

Answer (score 4):

It may be regarded opinion based, I assume.

The reason for that is there are huge numbers of alcoholic beverages and also huge number of coffee-based beverages. Make the calculation for each possible pairing and add people's preferences.

Maybe, such a thread may be less vulnerable: "Which coffee-based beverages get along together with Cognac?"

Still, this is just my opinion.

Comment: Even if there were some objective measure of how well an alcohol paired with a coffee type, I would still be inclined to flag the question as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the dangers of too-broad or opinion-based, I'd be okay with that question if it were aimed at a certain target, such as roast-level, application (e.g., pre-dinner/aperitif, after-dinner/digestif, dessert), content (cream/milk or no), flavouring (anisette, orange, fruit, ...).

That said, I'm having trouble identifying a spirit or liqueur that would *not* go with coffee... can you think of counter-examples?